# Eclipse Android cannot connect to public repository - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, google-code

I am using a Mac with Eclipse Galileo, trying to load Android code from a public repository.

I tried 'Checkout from SVN' and the URL is:

http://secrets-for-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/secrets-for-android-read-only

This is from the website:
http://code.google.com/p/secrets-for-android/source/checkout

I get the error:
Error validating location: "org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Bad URL passed to RA layer
svn: URL 'http://secrets-for-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/secrets-for-android-read-only' non-existent in revision 114"
Keep location anyway?

I'm currently using this svn client in Eclipse to manage my own secure repository on another website, so I know it's installed correctly and works.

Any ideas why checking out the public repo doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use http://secrets-for-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ location to check out. Read the page http://code.google.com/p/secrets-for-android/source/checkout carefully. I've just tried the location and all works perfectly.

Comment: Yes that works!  But why the space after ...trunk/ and the following text?  It was confusing to a new user of repositories like myself.

Comment: That's only needed for command line client I guess. I have no clue for what reason it is there though :) Read the command line client docs.